# Testing PHP files locally

Tags: php, testing, localhost, mamp

I created 2 php files (index.php and header.php). I am trying to test the "include" parameter for headers. I want to test the files locally on my Mac. I cant seem to get it to work.

I downloaded and installed MAMP and everything seems to be working fine. I pointed the document root to the correct folder. When I go to the //localhost:8888 I get a server error message.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to configure something or do something with the mysql database? Any help would be great.

Thanks.

**edit**

PHP files:

header.php:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>header</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> My Logo </h1>

<ul>
    <li> <a href=""> home </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> about </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> portfolio </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> contact </a> </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

index.php:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>header</title>
</head>
 <body>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>

<h2> blah blah blah </h2>

<p>
    dfgwgwergfwrgrgrjgjkfjkwfjwkfnkjnfwekjnfkjewnfknfwef <br />
    dkkngkjernjkeer er gk erjg jrek gjkerjkeg jker gerj ge <br />
    dfjdgnreg ergjer gjkerg erg er gjerjg kjer gjker gkerj gerk <br />
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Server Error Message:

"The website encountered an error while retrieving "http://localhost:8888/". It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.

HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: Can you include the full error message?

Comment: Like mike said.. The full message please. Also have you been able to load other pages? Or did the error occur when added the include? And if you could please post your PHP code that would be helpful. It is either your local environment is configured wrong. Or you have a syntax error.

Comment: Yea no problem. I'll edit my post. It's my first time with php so I'm sure there's something wrong. Its a very very simple test file.

Comment: what does your Apache error log say?

Comment: First result on google for `"apache error log" mamp`: http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/faq/where-can-i-find-the-logs/where-can-i-find-the-apache-error-log

Comment: this is the last entry:

[Wed Jul 18 20:10:43 2012] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Users/aaloktrivedi/Desktop/untitledfolder/untitledfolder

Comment: I re-pointed it to the root folder and the log says "resuming normal operations." But still not working

Comment: we need the message for the HTTP 500 error you told us about.

Comment: sorry. not sure where to find that. I can't seem to pull it out from the error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your XML tags in the first line of both files

Also, use only the essencial in the header.php. It isn0t needed but makes better code. Like this:

```
<h1> My Logo </h1>

<ul>
    <li> <a href=""> home </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> about </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> portfolio </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> contact </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that did it! (removing the xml tags). I knew it was going to be something simple and dumb. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If you need to create an XML page with PHP, perhaps later, there is some code you have to add first :P